# $H^1$ norm estimation of an affine function

Tags: inequality, sobolev-spaces

Let $v(x)=\alpha +(\beta-\alpha)x$ a function in $H^1(\Omega)$ with $\Omega=[0,1]$ and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants.
How do we prove that there exist an constant $M >0$ such that  $$||v||_{H^1} \leq M (|\alpha| + |\beta|)?$$
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $v(x)^2\leqslant 2\alpha^2+2(\beta-\alpha)^2x^2$, we have after an integration that $\lVert v\rVert_2\leqslant M_1\sqrt{\alpha^2+(\beta-\alpha)^2}$
where $M_1$ is a constant. This can be made small than $2M_1(|\alpha|+|\beta|)$ by the inequality $\sqrt{a+b}\leqslant \sqrt a+\sqrt b$ for non-negative $a$ and $b$.

Since $v'(x)=\beta-\alpha$, we have $\lVert v'\rVert_{L^2}\leqslant |\beta|+|\alpha|$.

Comment: $$||v||_{L^2} \leq M_1 (|\alpha|+|\beta - \alpha|)$$ how we found $$||v||_{L^2} \leq M_1 (|\alpha|+|\beta|)$$? and who is the value of $M_1?$

Comment: It's probably bounded by $2M_1(|\alpha|+|\beta|)$ (the exact value of the constant doesn't matter, I presume). You can compute explicitely the integral of the RHS of the first inequality in order to get the exact value of $M_1$.

Comment: and why $$||v||_{L^2} \leq M_1 (|\alpha|+|\beta - \alpha|)$$ ==> $$||v||_{L^2} \leq M_1 (|\alpha|+|\beta|)$$ how we can replace $|\beta - \alpha|$ by $|\beta|?$

Comment: ${}{}$See edit.

Comment: I don't understrand. We have: $$\sqrt{\alpha^2+(\beta - \alpha)^2} \leq \sqrt{\alpha^2} + \sqrt{(\beta-\alpha)^2}$$ so $$\leq |\alpha| +|\beta - \alpha|$$ But why we can write $$\leq |\alpha|+|\beta|$$?

Comment: I put a fact $2$ (then it should work).

Comment: please, step by step. We have $$v^(x)\leq 2\alpha^2+2(\beta - \alpha)^2 x^2$$ so $$||v||_{L^2}\leq \sqrt{2\alpha^2 + 2(\beta - \alpha)^2\int_0^1 x^2dx}$$ so $$\leq \sqrt{2\alpha^2 + 2 M_2 (\beta - \alpha)^2}$$ with $M_2=\int x^2dx$ then$$\leq \sqrt{\max (2,2M_2)[\alpha^2+(\beta - \alpha)^2}$$ we put $M_1=\max(2,2M_2)$,then$$||v||_{L^2}\leq M_1\sqrt{\alpha^2+(\beta - \alpha)^2}$$then $$\leq M_1(|\alpha|+|\beta-\alpha|)$$ then what's the others steps to found $$\leq 2M_1(|\alpha|+|\beta|)$$ please